# Why input from the form is not being passed

Tags: php, forms

I am new to php and have created two forms. One form takes in the user's first name and the second takes in the user's last name. I am not sure why that when the user inputs text into the forms nothing is being passed.

The php with the forms

```
<?php include '../view/header.php'; ?>
<div id="main">
     <h1>Add Athlete</h1>
     <form action="index.php" method="post" id="add_product_form">
         <input type="hidden" name="action" value="add_product" />

         <label>Country:</label>
         <select name="category_id">
         <?php foreach ( $categories as $category ) : ?>
             <option value="<?php echo $category['categoryID']; ?>">
                 <?php echo $category['categoryName']; ?>
             </option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
    <br />

    <label>Code:</label>
    <input type="input" name="code" />
    <br />

    <label>First Name:</label>
    <input type="input" name="first_name" />
    <br />

    <label>Last Name:</label>
    <input type="input" name="last_name" />
    <br />

    <label>&nbsp;</label>
    <input type="submit" value="Add Athlete" />
    <br />  <br />
  </form>
  <p><a href="index.php?action=list_products">View List of Olympic Athletes</a></p>

</div>
<?php include '../view/footer.php'; ?>
```

The php that takes in input from the forms

```
<?php
require('../model/database.php');
require('../model/product_db.php');
require('../model/category_db.php');

if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
    $action = $_POST['action'];
} else if (isset($_GET['action'])) {
   $action = $_GET['action'];
} else {
    $action = 'list_products';
}

if ($action == 'list_products') {
    // Get the current category ID
    $category_id = $_GET['category_id'];
    if (!isset($category_id)) {
        $category_id = 1;
}

// Get product and category data
$category_name = get_category_name($category_id);
$categories = get_categories();
$products = get_products_by_category($category_id);

  // Display the product list
  include('product_list.php');
} else if ($action == 'delete_product') {
    // Get the IDs
    $product_id = $_POST['product_id'];
    $category_id = $_POST['category_id'];

    // Delete the product
    delete_product($product_id);

    // Display the Product List page for the current category
    header("Location: .?category_id=$category_id");
} else if ($action == 'show_add_form') {
    $categories = get_categories();
    include('product_add.php');
} else if ($action == 'add_product') {
    $category_id = $_POST['category_id'];
    $first_name = "";
    if(isset($_POST['first_name'])){$first_name = $_POST['FirstName'];}
    $last_name = "";
    if(isset($_POST['last_name'])){$last_name = $_POST['LastName'];}



    // Validate the inputs
    if (empty($first_name) || empty($last_name)) {
        $error = "Invalid product data. Check all fields and try again.";
        include('../errors/error.php');
    } else {
        add_product($category_id, $first_name, $last_name);

        // Display the Product List page for the current category
        header("Location: .?category_id=$category_id");
    }
} else if ($action == 'list_categories') {
    $categories = get_categories();
    include('category_list.php');
} else if ($action == 'add_category') {
    $first_name = $_POST['FirstName'];

    // Validate inputs
    if (empty($name)) {
        $error = "Invalid category name. Check name and try again.";
        include('view/error.php');
    } else {
        add_category($name);
        header('Location: .?action=list_categories');  // display the Category List page
    }
} else if ($action == 'delete_category') {
    $category_id = $_POST['category_id'];
    delete_category($category_id);
    header('Location: .?action=list_categories');      // display the Category List page
}
?>
```

The `add_product` function

```
function add_product($category_id, $first_name, $last_name) {
    global $db;
    $query = "INSERT INTO products
                 (categoryID, FirstName, LastName)
              VALUES
                 ('$category_id', '$first_name', '$last_name')";
    $db->exec($query);
}
?>
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: @ravisachaniya in the php that is supposed to take in the user input for the forms, the if statement that validates the input is empty or not runs through the case of the input being empty.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides @MahfuzulAlam's answer, another problem is:

```
if(isset($_POST['first_name'])){$first_name = $_POST['FirstName'];}
                                                      ^^^^^^^^^

if(isset($_POST['last_name'])){$last_name = $_POST['LastName'];}
                                                    ^^^^^^^^
```

It should be:

```
if(isset($_POST['first_name'])){$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];}

if(isset($_POST['last_name'])){$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];}
```

Also, in PHP 7, there's a shorthand for what you are currently doing:

```
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'] ?? "";

$last_name = $_POST['last_name'] ?? "";
```

It's called [Null Coalesce Operator](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/isset_ternary).

Comment: I thought I has to do it that way so that the text from the form will get passing into the database. In database I have a value called `FirstName`

Comment: What does it have to do with the database? The DB is a separate matter. You are currently having problems with your HTTP data passing.  `$_POST['FirstName']` and `$_POST['LastName']` will always be null because don't have any PHP file that sends a POST method with those variables.

Comment: @Rax Weber Thanks for addressing. I also edited my answer with details.

@KeithCode No matter what's your column name. It won't affect as long as you pass `$first_name` and `$last_name` as value for `FirstName` and `LastName` columns.

Comment: @RaxWeber so I believe I understand now. The form will take in input and pass it to `$first_name` and `$last_name`. But then my `add_product` function in another php file has to take those values and pass them to the database. Am I right?

Comment: Exactly. Right you are. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Try using type = `text` not `input`. `<input type="text" name="last_name" />` and so on.

And there are problems in this code.

```
if(isset($_POST['first_name'])){$first_name = $_POST['FirstName'];}
if(isset($_POST['last_name'])){$first_name = $_POST['LastName'];}
```

Whatever you pass as first_name and last_name your `$first_name` and `$last_name` variables will be empty. Because you are using `$_POST['FirstName'], $_POST['LastName']` to set their values respectively, this don't really exists and both returning `NULL`. Rewrite these line as below:

```
if(isset($_POST['first_name'])){$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];}
if(isset($_POST['last_name'])){$first_name = $_POST['last_name'];}
```

Comment: If the `type` isn't recognized, it acts like `text`.

Comment: Yes. I checked that later. Problem was not actually in `type` , it was in code as mentioned. Thanks.